# jar that uses jogl obfuscation

Tags: java, jar, proguard, obfuscation, jogl

I use proguard gui as in [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vTgWPiRUCu4) to obfuscate the jar I created from a project in eclipse, which uses jogl. 
The original jar works great when is put in the directory of jogl dll files. The obfuscated file doesn't for some reason. The application starts but a blank window appears.
Any ideas why?

Comment: If jogl uses reflection (looking up classes by their names instead of using compile time references) ProGuard could happen to obfuscate those class names. http://www.alexeyshmalko.com/2014/proguard-real-world-example/

Comment: I dont know what should I do with the pom.xml, I used the GUI version of proguard

Answer (score 1):

This git project shows an example with exactly that problem:

https://github.com/ArlindNocaj/jogl_gradle

Running `gradle proguard` generates two jars, where the second one is the result of proguard with all obfuscation/shrinking/optimization deactivated.

Starting the result of proguard with `java -jar build/libs/proguard-jogl_gradle.jar` does not work.

Result:

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fb8fce79b0a, pid=32750, tid=140432495699712
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [ld-linux-x86-64.so.2+0x9b0a]
#
# Core dump written. Default location: /home/user/git/jogl_gradle/core or core.32750
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/user/git/jogl_gradle/hs_err_pid32750.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

I dont add the core dump, as the problem should be easily reproducable.

**EDIT**:Solution: Added the `-keepdirectories` option to make proguard add the directory entries to the jar. This allows to load classes using getResource method.

Comment: Solution: The difference between the jars is that the directory entries are by default not included by proguard. Adding ``` -keepdirectories ``` option to the proguard settings fixes this problem. Of course you also have to make sure that the JOGL packages are not obfuscated, if you use obfuscation.